Stop scanning of hyperistence
How can I disable scanning in Hibernate for my Spring Boot project to improve application deployment time and speed?
I need to reduce my deployment time.

Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to consider improving your question. What kind of "scanning" are you referring to? Did you mean "hypersistence" instead of "hyperistence"? What does it have to do with your question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
